# DataContract surrogate for amplified value type

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I want to use a custom aplified type (think Nullable) in a DataContract class.
I tried to write a `IDataContractSurrogate` but it fails at deserialization.

My amplified type looks like this:

```
public struct Amplified<TValue>
{
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
    //... some special code ...
}
```

And a DataContract may look like this:

```
[DataContract] public class MyDTO
{
     [DataMember] public Amplified<string> SpecialString { get; set; }
}
```

The above code works but produces unnecessary nesting with the Value property of amplified type. I want the DataContract to represent the Ampliefied just as a normal string on the wire.

Is this possible with the DataContract Serializers (JSON & Xml)?
Why do i get a InvalidCastException when using IDataContractSurrogate to replace Amplified with string?

Comment: Another info: the surrogate cast exception happens with an amplified Guid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use surrogates for primitive types (i.e., you'll be able to convert from `Amplified<T>` to `T` when T is a primitive, but not the other direction). For a possible alternative, take a look at the section "Fine grained control of serialization format for primitives" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/wcf-extensibility-serialization-callbacks.

Comment: Thx. That explains a lot. We solved the issue by using another serializer (Json.Net) by now.

Comment: @Carlosfigueira thanks you helped me answer part of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59619094/1938988) but if you had anymore insite on this it would be greatly appreciated