# WCF Enum By Value Surrogates to support dynamic enums

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

I'm trying to make WCF Support unnamed enums.  I've created a Surrogate which works fine when its an enum.   However when it's a nullable enum it fails on deserialization.  This is my surrogate which was modified from this [article](https://shulerent.com/2012/08/13/handling-invalid-enum-values-in-a-datacontractserializer/), my code differs since I don't want to supply known types:

```
public class EnumValueDataContractSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    #region Interface Implementation

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        return type;
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (null == obj)
        {
            return obj;
        }

        if (targetType.IsEnum)
        {
            return EnumExtensions.ChangeToUnderlyingType(targetType, obj);
        }

        if (targetType.IsNullable() && targetType.GetUnderlyingType().IsEnum)
        {
            return (int?)obj;
        }

        return obj;
    }

    // This Method is never invoked for targetType enum/enum?
    // However all the other parameters work fine
    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {

        if (targetType.IsNullable())
        {
            targetType = targetType.GetUnderlyingType();
        }

        if ((false == targetType.IsEnum) || (null == obj))
        {
            return obj;
        }

        var stringObj = obj as string;
        if (null != stringObj)
        {
            return Enum.Parse(targetType, stringObj);
        }
        return Enum.ToObject(targetType, obj);
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        //not used
        return;
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        //Not used
        return null;
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        //not used
        return null;
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        //not used
        return null;
    }

    public CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        //not used
        return typeDeclaration;
    }

    #endregion
}

public static object ChangeToUnderlyingType(Type enumType, object value)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType));
}
```

When the Enum is not nullable everything deserialized fine.
When the Enum is nullable, with a value, WCF will not deserialize the int to Enum.

**EDIT:**

I think this may be related to how WCF handles Deserialization from Surrogates.  Here's a few behaviors I've noticed that might be helpful.

1. When calling `GetDeserializedObject` the `object obj` will be populated with an object that has already been deserialized.  e.g it looks like WCF deserialization kicks in before the surrogate does
2. When calling with an the with the underlying type the `GetDeserializedObject` is actually never hit, I think this is because surrogate Deserialization only works on objects
3. WCF Cannot Serialize Enums to the value but it handles deserializing from the value just fine.

**Resources:**

This is the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates#getdeserializedobject-method) for datacontract surrogates

How can I get nullable (and non-nullable) Enums to serialize and deserialize strictly from values?

Comment: Well, according to documents `GetDeserializedObject` method is called after the deserialization process. If that fails that method won't be called. They only way to intercept it before the deserialization is modifying `GetDataContractType` method. I'm not sure but if the enum contracts passed into this method you may intercept how they ared deserialized.

Comment: @Eldar yeah, I've been trying to play around with deserialization I thought this was how to do but I haven't been able to get it working. If you know of any way for it to consistently serialize enums as their value, I'll accept that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Below line not let you handle `Nullable<Enum>` types :

```
  if ((false == targetType.IsEnum) || (null == obj))
  {
      return obj;
  }
```

You also need to check `Nullable<>` type explicitly. Like below :

```
if (targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
    targetType = targetType.GetGenericArguments()[0];   
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oXnhYP) that demonstrates it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I forgot to fix that when posting the question.  My issue is that the deserialize method never hits for that parameter.  WCF never invokes the method

Comment: WCF has logic internally to ignore certain params during surrogate deserialization, but it's not fully documented so I cant figure out why

Comment: Although this is not the answer to my question,  you're the only person who made an attempt to solve it, so enjoy :)

Comment: @johnny5 can you share some data contracts and samples how you want to serialize/deserialize them. And how your client generates the client proxy via dlls or wsdl or mex endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as an update.  I have this working farther than before the following serializes properly now:

1. named values for non-nullable enums
2. unnamed values for non-nullable enums
3. named values for nullable enums

Note: I've omitted the trivial methods from the surrogate as they've remained the same:

```
public class EnumValueDataContractSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (targetType.IsEnum && !Enum.IsDefined(targetType, obj))
        {
            return EnumExtensions.ChangeToUnderlyingType(targetType, obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**
It important to mention 2 things I've observed.

1. GetObjectToSerialize targetType is never null, WCF handles stripping the null for us.
2. Despite WCF not be able to handle serialization of enums as values, WCF has no problem converting back to the enum non-nullable enum, Hence forth why there now is no code in the `GetDeserializedObject`

**Disclaimer:**  this is observation based programming, I could not find anything to fully support my claim in WCF Documentation.  (But if WCF had good documentation I wouldn't be here in the first place)

The only thing that isn't working is unnamed values for nullable enums...